# Wifi doesn't work on Lenovo B590 with Broadcom BCM4313

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop, broadcom

My son bougt a laptop.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04. First wifi worked fine now it keeps searching but can't connect. I tried some solutions but I think I need help.

lspci -nn | grep 
028002:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

These are the data.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried search for the propriotary drivers? They might show up there.

Answer (score 5):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did that. Now I can connect but the connection is weak. There is a special driver for the BCM4313 that I find in the "extra driver" section. When I install that wifi isn't connecting. I read in ubuntu forums that 12.10 does a better job with Broadcom so I'm going to install that. I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi, I installed 12.10 64 bit and it works fine now! It recognizes the Broadcom BCM4313 and installs it correctly. After that I installed Minecraft and the updates and after reboot.. no wireless at all! I installed 12.10 again without updates, now it works fine. I'm afraid to install updates now. So I won't do that until it's nessecary.

Comment: Which driver is it using successfully in 12.10? b43 or wl? Find out with: lsmod

Comment: Hi,
lsmod give me a whole list, these are the lines that include 'wl'. Thanks!

wl                   2573568  0
bluetooth             209199  11 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
lib80211               14381  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl

Comment: I think it will work fine if you install linux-headers-generic and then update. The update should then install a newer bcmwl-kernel-source, if available, and linux-headers and I suspect you'll be fine.